# Time gap in Pivot Chart using Power Pivot

Tags: excel, charts, powerpivot

I'm hoping someone can help with this.  I'm having a problem displaying a time interval on my pivot chart where there is no data.  I am charting orders by week number for each year. As you can see from the attached picture, there are missing week numbers in my chart which I want to fill in. I have a fact table which I'm using for order count, and it is connected in the data model to a date lookup table with one instance of each date from 2012 thru 2020. As you can see from the chart, I'm missing weeks 10, 11, 13-17, 21, 27, etc. There are no orders for those weeks, however, those weeks are in my data table which is connected in the data model. I would like these dates to show up on my chart's axis. I am doing this in Excel version 2016.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you right click on the background of the chart (the whitespace under the Legend that says Total) and choose PivotChart Options then go to the Display tab, you should be able to choose "Show items with no data on axis fields" and click the checkbox. That should cause those time gaps to show up.

If you also have a PivotTable for this same dataset the checkbox may say "on rows" instead of "on axis".

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2010

Right click the pivot table

Layout & Print tab

Tick Show Items with no data